# LINQ Order by another property is the first property is equal to a given value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to order a list by published date which are set manually by the user. If the published date is not set I want to order by created date instead (which is set automatically by the system).

This is what I've tried so far but it seems as though the collection is only ordered by created date even though the published date value isn't equal to its' default value:

```
viewModel.News = model.Content.Children<NewsItem>().OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate == default(DateTime) ? x.CreateDate : x.PublishDate).ToList();
```

FYI The PublishDate and CreatedDate properties are read only.

Comment: The database is probably returning for an null DataTime DBNull and not the default DateTime 1/1/1

Answer (score 1):

Is it allowable to order by created date when published date is the same? If yes then you can use this approach with [ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ThenBy__2_System_Linq_IOrderedEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__):

```
viewModel.News = model.Content.Children<NewsItem>().OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate).ThenBy(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell us whether your sequence of `model.Content.Children<NewsItem>()` is an `IEnumerable` or an `IQueryable`.

If you don't know what this means: is your process then one that will do the enumeration, or is another process, like a database management system fetching the data for you?

If the sequence if `IEnumerable`, my advise would be to create a Compare class that does the comparison for you. The advantage would be, that if in future you decide to order differently, your LINQ won't change. The disadvantage: this won't work with databases (that is why I asked whether it was IQueryable). The IEnumerable case is at the end.

### IQueryable

IQueryable is most often used when the query is to be executed by another process, like a database management system. Because it is to be executed by someone else, functionality is limited to fairly simple functions. After all: you might have create a `VeryUsefulFunction()`, but SQL does not know this.

> If the published date is not set I want to order by created date instead

So we need a select where you extract the OrderDate: either PublishedDate, or CreatedDate. After that you can order by OrderDate

```
var result = model.Content.Children<NewsItem>().Select(newsItem => new
{
    OrderDate = newsItem.PublishedDate ?? newsItem.CreatedDate,
    Item = newsItem,
})
.OrderBy(newsItem => newsItem.OrderDate)

// if desired, throw away the OrderDate:
.Select(newsItem => newsItem.Item)
```

Several LINQ-to-entities won't accept the null coalescing operator (??). In that case you will get an exception at run-time. If that's the case you'll need to use the ternary operator (?:)

### IEnumerable

You could use the IQueryable code also as Enumerable. However, in that case you would mix the concept of "earlier newsItem" with your processing, making them less readable, less testable and less changeable. For instance, if you need the concept of ordering news items over and over again, you would have to copy-paste this code. Besides, if in future you want to order differently, for instance order by news item length, you'll need to find and rewrite all your LINQ statements that order the news items.

Better would be to define which news item comes before another news item. For this you write a class that implements `IComparer<NewsItem>`.

```
class NewsItemComparer : IComparer<NewsItem>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<NewsItem> Default = new NewsItemComparer();
    private static readonly IComparer<DateTime> dateComparer = Comparer<DateTime>.Default;

    public int Compare(NewsItem x, NewItem y)
    {
        // TODO: decide what to do if x or y NULL: exception? first? last?

        return dateComparer.Compare(x.PublishedDate ?? x.CreatedDate,
                                    y.PublishedDate ?? y.CreatedDate);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = model.Content.Children<NewsItem>()
    .OrderBy(newsItem => newsItem, NewsItemComparer.Default);
```

This looks much neater than putting the comparison code inside your query. If you decide to compare differently, this code, and all others that want to compare your NewsItems won't change. It is even fairly simple to implement various comparison methods, for instance by Date, or by Length, or by Author, ...